# How to skip other languages when decoding HTML entities

Tags: perl

This code block contains different languages and HTML entities.

Here is the function. Please suggest a solution to this. As it stands it changes all the other languages too.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use HTML::Entities;
use Encode;

my $a = "&reg; , &ordf; , &Ntilde; , &sbquo; , &icirc; , &ocirc; , &aelig; , &ecirc; , &szlig; , &scaron; , &ugrave;";
my $b = "Pessimo il servizio della climatizzazione. Da migliorare la ristorazione.";
my $c = "先秦兩漢 &reg;&reg;&reg; 儒家 孔子家語 子貢問(疑為「子夏問 曲禮子貢問第四十二，子夏問第四十三，疑誤植為「子貢問";
my $d = "漢字仮名交じり文";
my $e = "Очень хорошо все понравилась";

decode_entities($a);
decode_entities($b);
decode_entities($c);
decode_entities($d);
decode_entities($e);

open(OUT,">test.xml");
print OUT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'."\n";
print OUT "<Tag1>$a</Tag1>\n";
print OUT "<Tag2>$b</Tag2>\n";
print OUT "<Tag3>$c</Tag3>\n";
print OUT "<Tag4>$d</Tag4>\n";
print OUT "<Tag5>$e</Tag5>\n";
close(OUT);
```

I want to to change *only* HTML Names / HTML Numbers to HTML symbols. All other data must be kept as it is.

Comment: `decode_entities()` won't do anything to those characters. What specific issue are you having? I think you're blaming it on the wrong component.

Comment: Your source code cannot possibly contain what you say it does. Without `use utf8;`, the source is expected to be US-ASCII, and `先` is not an ASCII character.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what the problem is, but it looks like it's nothing to do with `HTML::Entities`.

Firstly, you have written a UTF-8-encoded program without telling Perl about the encoding; and secondly you are writing UTF-8 to a file handle that isn't set up for it.

In addition you also *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program; the `-w` switch on the shebang line *will not do*. And you should use the three-parameter form of `open`, and either check the status of each one or `use autodie` which will do it for you if you have version 10 or later of Perl 5.

You also shouldn't *ever* use variables `$a` or `$b` outside a `sort` block.

So you program should look like this

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Entities;

my @strings = (
    '&reg; , &ordf; , &Ntilde; , &sbquo; , &icirc; , &ocirc; , &aelig; , &ecirc; , &szlig; , &scaron; , &ugrave;',
    'Pessimo il servizio della climatizzazione. Da migliorare la ristorazione.',
    '先秦兩漢 &reg;&reg;&reg; 儒家 孔子家語 子貢問(疑為「子夏問 曲禮子貢問第四十二，子夏問第四十三，疑誤植為「子貢問',
    '漢字仮名交じり文',
    'Очень хорошо все понравилась',
);

decode_entities($_) for @strings;

open my $out_fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'test.xml'
        or die qq{Unable to open "test.xml" for output: $!};
print $out_fh qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n};
print $out_fh "<Tag1>$_</Tag1>\n" for @strings;
close $out_fh;
```

On my system, this puts the following text into `test.xml`, which is what I would expect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Tag1>® , ª , Ñ , ‚ , î , ô , æ , ê , ß , š , ù</Tag1>
<Tag1>Pessimo il servizio della climatizzazione. Da migliorare la ristorazione.</Tag1>
<Tag1>先秦兩漢 ®®® 儒家 孔子家語 子貢問(疑為「子夏問 曲禮子貢問第四十二，子夏問第四十三，疑誤植為「子貢問</Tag1>
<Tag1>漢字仮名交じり文</Tag1>
<Tag1>Очень хорошо все понравилась</Tag1>
```

---

**Commentary**

For those interested, Google Translate provides the following

- `$strings[1]` **Italian**  *Bad service of air conditioning. To improve the food.*
- `$strings[2]` **Chinese (Han)** *Qin and Han ®®® Confucian Analects of Confucius, Zi Gong asked (suspected "Zi Xia asked Music Man Zi Gong asked the forty-second, forty-third Zi Xia asked, suspected Mistransplant as" Zi Gong asked*
- `$strings[3]` **Chinese (Han)**  *Character Fan Wen name post ji ri*
- `$strings[4]` **Russian**  *Very well liked all*

Comment: Thnaks for your guidance. I am also getting same output but in notepad++ only. When I try this with browser it get's failed and also vi editor(Putty) doesn't show the proper output and failed at xmllint command